# How can I split a string into character labels and numeric values in R?

Tags: r, string, split

Struggling newbie here, please pardon ungraceful explanations, and let me know what I need to clarify.

I have an object that like this, a vector of strings:

> "aaaa,1,1,1,1,0"
> "abba,0,0,1,1,1"
> "bbaa,1,0,0,0,1"

I'd like to split out the four-letter labels as a character vector and the remainder I would like to reconstitute as numbers so that I'd end up with a dataframe like this, 3 obs of 6 variables, with the labels as character and the numbers as numeric:

> aaaa 1 1 1 1 0
> abba 0 0 1 1 1
> bbaa 1 0 0 0 1

And then I want to add "column labels" to it and end up with

> NAME 1 2 3 4 5
> aaaa 1 1 1 1 0
> abba 0 0 1 1 1
> bbaa 1 0 0 0 1

and I'd also like a pony.

I feel like I have bits and pieces...I can split out the four letter labels using

`substr(data,1,4)` and that works to get a vector like

"aaaa", "abba", "bbaa".

But I cannot figure out what to use to get the rest of the string, the number part, back as a vector. `substr(data,5,last)` doesn't work and I prefer not to say `substr(data,5,14)` because despite my example here the strings won't always be 14 characters long. Is there a way to specify `substr(data,5,"to the end of the string?")`

Then, to convert the string to numbers I was trying

`as.integer(unlist(strsplit(data,",")))`

On the original file and I got back a single long vector with 1s and 0s but where the labels, the "aaba"s were replaced with NAs.

I'm stuck trying to put all the pieces together.

[Why do I have my numbers and labels mixed together in a string in the first place, you might ask? Because I wanted to replace all instances of "1,0,1" with "1,1,1" and using `paste()` to convert the numbers to strings and using `gsub()` on the strings to effect the replacement was the only way I could get that to work.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started on the right path. I had to add a few more steps, but I got the following to work:

```
input = c(
    "aaaa,1,1,1,1,0",
    "abba,0,0,1,1,1",
    "bbaa,1,0,0,0,1"
)

df = type.convert(
    as.data.frame(
        matrix(unlist(strsplit(input, ',')), byrow = TRUE, nrow = length(input))),
    as.is = TRUE
)
```

Comment: just do `read.csv(text = input, header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. In base R, run `substr(data, 5, length(data))`.
2. If you’re open to using another package, try `stringr`. Then you can just use -1 to indicate the end of the vector. Try `stringr::str_sub(data, 5, -1)`

Comment: Thanks mgf! That is two great solutions for splitting the initial strings in two.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Now I still need to convert from "aaaa", "1,1,1,1,0" to aaaa 1 1 1 1 0, that is, to take the second character string "1,1,1,1,0" and convert it to numbers, still 'attached' to the four letter label.

Answer (score 1):

I think BigFinger's answer performs almost all of the desired functionality but in order to change the column names as well, you can add
`names(df) <- c("NAME",1,2,3,4,5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(input) %>% 
  separate(input, into=LETTERS[1:6], sep = ",", convert = TRUE)
```

```
 A         B     C     D     E     F
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 aaaa      1     1     1     1     0
2 abba      0     0     1     1     1
3 bbaa      1     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vectors form a comma separated file so just use `read.csv`.

You can add the names as the first string and use `header=TRUE`.  `1`,`2`,etc are not good names for columns, R will try to fix them but if you're sure you want them use `check.names=FALSE` to keep them as they are.

```
> read.csv(text=c("NAME,1,2,3,4,5",x), header=TRUE,check.names = FALSE)

  NAME 1 2 3 4 5
1 aaaa 1 1 1 1 0
2 abba 0 0 1 1 1
3 bbaa 1 0 0 0 1
```